# XCode building files into app

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

I have a project inside XCode that I'm compiling into a .app file for iOS. The problem that I'm getting is that the files(non source code files) in my app are being compiled into the wrong directory of my application. For example a file thats in myproject/media/intro/movie.avi is being built into myproject.app/movie.avi and it should be built into myproject.app/media/intro/movie.avi

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix this issue, you need to import the complete folder "media" with option 
**Create Folder references for any folder added** in the **folder** radio button while selecting folder.

Comment: at the moment you were using `Create Groups for any added folders`